# Listener for RadioButton for change Fragments

Tags: android, oncheckedchanged

I need to switch fragments at the application with tabs (RadioButton). What is the event listener should I use? onClick or onCheckedChanged? If it is possible to example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For single `RadioButton`  you can use `OnClickListener` as follows:

```
         OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                      RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
                      Toast.makeText(your_Activity.this, rb.getText(), 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
         };

         RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
         rb1.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

In case of `RadioGroup` you need to use `OnCheckedChangeListener` as follows :

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected

            switch(checkedId) {
                  case R.id.radioButton1:
                       // switch to fragment 1                
                       break;
                  case R.id.radioButton2:
                      // Fragment 2
                      break;
                  case R.id.radioButton3:
                      // Fragment 3
                      break;
            }   
        }
    });
```

The onCheckedChanged callback receives the ID of the newly checked button in the checkedId parameter.

Comment: I have a few classes extend Fragment in a FrameLayout. And changed for a click. onCheckedChanged will be work on that or better used onClick?